# get_option compatible with wordpress network (multisite)?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have this function in a plugin that works on wp install but it doesnt work on wordpress MU.

```
 if( !get_option( $option-name ) ) {
        // something
            } else {
    // something else
    }
```

How can I make the get_option compatible with Multisite install.

// I am using redux framework, I created an option and I wanted to have a conditional to check if the option is used or not.. but it worked fine on the wp install but not on MU one.

Thanks

Comment: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3925/stop-replying-with-it-doesnt-work

Comment: How can I ask about that then?

Comment: The same way you write code, in a precise and complete way. Don't let the reader guess what you mean.

Comment: `get_option()` is completely compatible with multisite, given that it's one of the most used APIs the abhorrent amount of things wouldn't work otherwise. Please elaborate and what is your expected and actual result.

Comment: I think you are looking for `get_site_option()`.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option.  `get_site_option()` pulls from the `site_meta` table... while `get_option` pulls from the corresponding sites `wp_options` table.

Answer (score 9):

When working with multisites, there are two commonly used sets of functions for pulling/updated options.

Now... how you structure your options and save them to the database is up to you.  It depends on the functionality your plugin is adding, and where you want to store/pull options.

**Single Site Configuration**

`get_option()` and `update_option()` are used to interact with the `wp_options` table.  This table is specific to each blog id.  You may have a `wp_options_2` and a `wp_options_3` table; where `2` and `3` correspond to that blogs id.

If you use `get_option()` in your code... it is going to look for that option in the corresponding blog id's `wp_options` table.  This means every sub-site could have a different value here.

**Multi Site Configuration**

The other set of functions are `get_site_option()` and `update_site_option()`.  These two functions are used to interact with the `site_meta` table.  The `site_meta` table exists only once.. and is used for global options for all subsites.

If you use `get_site_option()` in your code... it is going to pull that option from the `site_meta` table.  In other words, each subsite will use the same option from the `site_meta` table.

**Custom Code to Check if Multisite is Active**

What I do when I code a plugin that needs to be multisite compatible.. is add a custom function to check and see if the site is a network install.  If it is... I pull from site meta... if it is not, I pull from site options.

```
// First, I define a constant to see if site is network activated
if ( ! function_exists( 'is_plugin_active_for_network' ) ) {
    // Makes sure the plugin is defined before trying to use it
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
}
if (is_plugin_active_for_network('my_plugin_folder/main.php')) {  // path to plugin folder and main file
    define("THIS_PLUGIN_NETWORK_ACTIVATED", true);
}
else {
    define("THIS_PLUGIN_NETWORK_ACTIVATED", false);
}

// Wordpress function 'get_site_option' and 'get_option'
function get_this_plugin_option($option_name) {

    if(THIS_PLUGIN_NETWORK_ACTIVATED== true) {

        // Get network site option
        return get_site_option($option_name);
    }
    else {

        // Get blog option
        return get_option($option_name);
    }
}

// Wordpress function 'update_site_option' and 'update_option'
function update_this_plugin_option($option_name, $option_value) {

    if(THIS_PLUGIN_NETWORK_ACTIVATED== true) {

        // Update network site option
        return update_site_option($option_name, $option_value);
    }
    else {

    // Update blog option
    return update_option($option_name, $option_value);
    }
}
```

Now, we can simply use `get_this_plugin_option()` or `update_this_plugin_option()`; and our code will determine if the site is network activated or not.. and update or get the option from the corresponding options table.

This prevents having to write code twice.. or use two separate hooks when coding for network activations.

Comment: Thanks alot for everyone and thanks to Josh for the detailed tutorial, It helped me alot to understand how things go with the get_option() and get_site_option()..I am actually using redux framework. I created an option and I wanted to make the conditional that checks IF the option is used or not.. and I've got stuck in the MU framework.. I will try out all what you said. and for I think I should edit my question to explain my question better. Thanks to everyone

Comment: I just modified lazy-invitation plugin with this. Thank you so much...

Comment: You're extremely welcome.  I still use the code to this day :)  Sorry for late reply; lost my login info for the longest time!  Stay awesome!!

Comment: "If you use get_option() in your code... it is going to look for that option in the corresponding blog id's wp_options table." What corresponding blog id? You're not passing a blog id to get_option...

Comment: @AlxVallejo you dont pass a blog id to get_option() - it uses the id of the current blog that you're viewing. You can use get_current_blog_id() to see the value

Comment: I wonder what's the advantage of using `is_plugin_active_for_network` over simply using `is_multisite` which would give you cleaner code?